# How to fetch nested relations on Kinvey

Tags: angularjs, kinvey

So I'm working in an AngularJs app that is connected to a Kinvey backend. *www.kinvey.com*

In Kinvey we can fetch an entity and it's relations like this:

```
var promise = $kinvey.DataStore.get('events', 'event-id', {
    relations : { location: 'locations' }
});
```

***http://devcenter.kinvey.com/angular/guides/datastore#JoiningOperators***

**Relational Data / Fetching**

The above is actually getting an event entity from the events collection and it's also fetching the data of the locations associated to it (which are in a different collection), so far so good we are able to retrieve an entity and it's associated entities ...

**Now how could I retrieve the associations of those locations ?

In other words how can I retrieve nested associations ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$kinvey.DataStore.find('collection1', null, {
  relations: {
    name: "collection2",
    "name.name": "collection3"
  }
});
```

https://support.kinvey.com/discussion/201272198/nested-relations